# How to regex validate numbers with One letter in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

using Laravel 5.6. and In my RegisterController I have NIC input to store values to table like this,

```
'nic' => 'required',
```

now I need regex validation to nic input with nine numbers and last capital V letters input as an example `521463258V` like this. how can I give regex validation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use as this

```
'nic' => 'required|regex:/^\d{9}V$/',
```

Comment: Thank you this works. this is work for input 9 characters ends with V. if not it will display the error. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a regex validation:

```
'nic' => [
    'required',
    'regex:/^[0-9]{9}[A-Z]$/',
];
```

If you only have a `V` as last element, just set it fixed:

```
    'regex:/^[0-9]{9}V$/',
```

Comment: I need only capital V letter end

Comment: @Muru then the second option will do the job :)

Comment: this is also not sucess brcause when I enter like this value `12546325T` it is not validated.

Comment: You said before that only `V` at the end ia acceptable. If you need different letters at the end, then use the first option. ([A-Z])

Comment: If `V` or `T` are the only allowed end chars then `[TV]` would be most accurate. @Muru Make up your mind already and formulate good question. Getting this simple REGEX right shouldn't require multiple rounds of teeth-pulling.

Comment: I need `V` letter at the end like this `123456789V`

Comment: You need to define the pattern. Is 9 number + 1 letter, right? What letters are possible here? T, V, any other?

Answer (score 1):

If letter `V` is the only letter that must be at the end, then here you go.

```
'nic' => [
    'required',
    'regex:/^\d{9}V$/',
];
```

Comment: @Oen44 You should end with a dollar `$` or else `123456789V1` is valid.

Comment: Cool. No clue who DV but have a UV from me.

Comment: @Oen44 yes it is

Comment: @Muru Be specific, you are saying that you need to match with capital V, then you are saying that you need different letters? I'm confused.